# Android Mx10 Tv Box update error E: failed to map file

Tags: android, android-tv, television, tvbox

I bought a MX10 TV Box exactly the fallowing, as in [geekbuying](https://www.geekbuying.com/item/MX10-Android-7-1-2-RK3328-4GB-32GB-TV-Box-386668.html), and I want to update it. I don't know how to connect by USB it has not micro USB. I've tried End to END USB A cable but it is not identifying by **RKBatchTool-v1.8** tool and when I using SD card `.img` images are not visible. I read that image should be in `zip` file. I've compressed them but when using Android Recovery The fallowing error shows up.

[image]

**used cable**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press the reset button inside the AV port and keep it pressed
Connect the TV Box via USB to PC (A-A blue USB cable)
Let go reset button

Comment: thanks for your pay attention unfortunately it is not working and did not detecting by computer. I've tried usb 2 and usb 3 ports. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

By this 4pda [post](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=910596&st=80#entry79173284) you need to check your board name (after disassembling a tv box). If your board name look like this - MXQ-RK3328-**D4**_A, then your img name should be called like that - mxq_rk3328_**d4**_8.1_8189-6051_20180828_r1.img. If your board name without **d4**, then you should find img build without **d4** postfix name.

[image: Board name]

Also should be mentioned, when I upgrade by OTA - zip file. I have a recovery.img file with zip one. And you can't do zip build just by zipping img. They differs and while building Android build by SDK, this files are  separate in output directory.

All tools should be run with admin permission.

As [ts18056](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9233821/ts18056) mentioned, find a button inside the AV port.

- Download and install Android Console [Tool](https://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frockchip-linux%2Ftools%2Fraw%2Fmaster%2Fwindows%2FAndroidTool_Console_v2.4.zip&e=79173284).
- Open Android Console Tool -> Upgrade firmware -> Firmware.
- Choose your img build/firmware.
- Activate Fastboot mode by pressing button inside AV port, install USB while pressing this button (E2E USB A cable into the USB port near HDMI port).
- Below should be the message `Found One LOADER Devices` after that stop pushing the AV port button.
- Press UPGRADE.
- Go to the TV and install the TV STB (First turn on will take 3-5 mins).

You can find firmware [here](https://chinagadgetsreviews.com/?s=mx10) and other instructions / upgrade methods.

Maybe you can burn it with like Amlogic board, but I'm not sure with that.

In case of Amlogic boards you need a CP2102 USB UART Board (type A) with E2E USB A cable. After a UART connection to the board, through kermit tool set the board to burn mode. Then you can burn an img build with Amlogic USB Burning Tool or with [this bash script](https://forum.khadas.com/t/burning-tools-for-linux-pc/1832).